# insert a sound when you press a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have to play a sound when I press the start button. I have the following code founded on the internet, which doesn't work:

```
  playSound function (soundfile) {
                            document.getElementById ("dummy"). innerHTML = 
                            "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />"; 
                        } 

<input type="button" class="finish" onclick="playSound('button.wav')" id="pulsante1"/>
```

I do not understand why, maybe because my button is already an action when pressed? namely:

```
 $ (this). on ('click', refreshValues​​);
```

and this:

```
$ ("input.finish.") on ("click", function () {
                                    tot + = parseInt ($ (this). val ()); 
                                    document.getElementById ("total"). value = tot; 
                                    });
```

how can I fix it??

Comment: show your html. also, why dont you use html5 audio tags?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
function playSound() 
{
    $('audio').remove(); 
    $('body').append('<audio class="sound"><source src="/assets/sounds/alert.mp3"></source><source src="./sounds/alert.ogg"></source></audio>');
    $('.sound')[0].play();
}

$('#startbtn').on('click', playSound​​);
```

Comment: and to do that start with onclick leave what I wrote??